# excel vba - multiple criteria index match

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to do a multiple criteria index match function in vba but I can't seem to get the results.
The code I used is the following:

```
  wsDest.Range(wsDest.Cells(i, X), wsDest.Cells(i, X)) = _
  Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(wsSour.Range("C3:C8763"), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(wsDest.Cells(i, 1) & "&" & wsDest.Cells(i, 2), _
      wsSour.Range("A3:A8763") & "&" & wsSour.Range("B3:B8763"), 0), 0)
```

For the match portion I was trying to use excel's method of

`=MATCH(criteria1 & criteria2,range1 & range2,0)`

Comment: '&' is concatinate strings operator, i.e. "a" & "b" becomes "ab". You can not use '&' for put two ranges together. Do you try to fine a index on which criteria1 matches in range1 at that index and criteria2 matches in range2 at that index by the formula "MATCH(criteria1 & criteria2,range1 & range2,0)"? That will not work, because 'Match' does not have such function.

Comment: @Fumu7 - you *can* use MATCH() to do this on a worksheet.  See for example - http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/two-column-lookup.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `WorkSheet.Evaluate` method to do this.

Here's a simple example:

[image]

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim v, sht, a1, a2

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    a1 = sht.Cells(7, 1).Address(False, False)
    a2 = sht.Cells(7, 2).Address(False, False)

    v = sht.Evaluate("MATCH(" & a1 & "&" & a2 & ",A2:A5&B2:B5,0)")

    sht.Range("B9") = v

End Sub
```

EDIT: here's a more robust example taking into account the different sheets

```
Sub Tester2()

    Dim v, shtDest, shtSrc, a1, a2, i

    Set shtDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dest")
    Set shtSrc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source")

    i = 1

    a1 = "'" & shtDest.Name & "'!" & shtDest.Cells(i, 1).Address(False, False)
    a2 = "'" & shtDest.Name & "'!" & shtDest.Cells(i, 2).Address(False, False)

    Debug.Print a1, a2

    v = shtSrc.Evaluate("MATCH(" & a1 & "&" & a2 & ",A2:A9&B2:B9,0)")

    If Not IsError(v) Then
        shtDest.Cells(i, 3).Value = shtSrc.Range("C2:C9").Cells(v).Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, *Evaluate* always treat formula as *array formula*. +1

Comment: @Tim Williams Thanks! I'll give this a try! But what if I the lookup array not to be a string? Can I do "," & (range1) & "&" & (range2) &",0)")?