# Multiple Criteria, Multiple Column Match

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to code a multiple match to check if a record exists in a table before adding a new one. I've been trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790846/excel-vba-multiple-criteria-index-match) example using 'Evaluate' and 'Match' to compare. I would rather use match than a loop as eventually the table could be pretty big.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Rem SheetString = Worksheets(WorkSite).Range("E1").Address(False, False, , True) & "&" & TblRng.Range(1, j).Offset(-5, 0).Address(False, False, , True) & "&" & TblRng.Range(1, j).Offset(-6, 0).Address(False, False, , True) & "&" & TblRng.Range(1, j).Offset(-2, 0).Address(False, False, , True)
SheetString = Worksheets(WorkSite).Range("E1").Address(False, False, , True) & "&" & _
    TblRng.Range(1, j).Offset(-5, 0).Address(False, False, , True) & "&" & _
    TblRng.Range(1, j).Offset(-6, 0).Address(False, False, , True) & "&" & _
    TblRng.Range(1, j).Offset(-2, 0).Address(False, False, , True)

Rem RangeString = TblTrspt.ListColumns(1).Range.Address(False, False, , True) & "&" & TblTrspt.ListColumns(2).Range.Address(False, False, , True) & "&" & TblTrspt.ListColumns(3).Range.Address(False, False, , True) & "&" & TblTrspt.ListColumns(4).Range.Address(False, False, , True)
RangeString = TblTrspt.ListColumns(1).Range.Address(False, False, , True) & "&" & _
    TblTrspt.ListColumns(2).Range.Address(False, False, , True) & "&" & _
    TblTrspt.ListColumns(3).Range.Address(False, False, , True) & "&" & _
    TblTrspt.ListColumns(4).Range.Address(False, False, , True)

Eval = Application.Evaluate("MATCH(" & SheetString & "," & RangeString & ",0)")

If IsError(Eval) Then
'add new item if not already in list
```

`SheetString` is the criteria, `RangeString` is the table to be checked against. They need to be checked together as the combination may be unique but each field will be present several times.

Currently I cannot get this code to compile as I get "Application-defined object-defined error" on the line to set `SheetString`.

Comment: You need to put WorkSite into apostrophes (`"`) at least. Apart form that I am having some trouble deciphering what you are trying to do, may because I am not very familiar with with what TblRng etc. is. Hmm, and since you are using VBA anyway, is there some reason you are using `MATCH` instead of `FIND`?

Comment: What is the address of the `TblRng` range?

Comment: The code cycles through several worksheets, the range is set to a listobjects table on the relevant sheet:

TblRng = Worksheets(WorkSite).Range("Tbl" & WorkSite)

I couldnt work out how to use FIND with multiple criteria across columns.

Comment: It seems that you are trying to match several items at once. Could you please `debug.print` `SheetString` & `RangeString` variables in the immediate window and post here the result so we can see what values are actually passed to the match formula

Comment: Even with WorkSite as "Worksite" SheetString I get a "Subscript out of range" err.

RangeString is as follows:

    debug.Print RangeString
'[LBA-LogiCal_CC_150603.xlsm]TransportDefine'!B4:B158&'[LBA-LogiCal_CC_150603.xlsm]TransportDefine'!C4:C158&'[LBA-LogiCal_CC_150603.xlsm]TransportDefine'!D4:D158&'[LBA-LogiCal_CC_150603.xlsm]TransportDefine'!E4:E158

Comment: Replace `TblRng.Range(1,` with `TblRng.Cells(1,` in the `SheetString` formula

Comment: Replaced to

`SheetString = Worksheets("WorkSite").Cells("E1").Address(False, False, , True) & "&" & TblRng.Cells(1, j).Offset(-5, 0).Address(False, False, , True) & "&" & TblRng.Cells(1, j).Offset(-6, 0).Address(False, False, , True) & "&" & TblRng.Cells(1, j).Offset(-2, 0).Address(False, False, , True)`

but still get the 'Subscript out of range' error.

Comment: You should have replaced only those who were like `TblRng.Range(1` not `.Range("E1")`. (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx)

Comment: Ok, that is working now and the code compiles:

RangeString 
`"'[LBA-LogiCal_CC_150603.xlsm]TransportDefine'!B4:B5&'[LBA-LogiCal_CC_150603.xlsm]TransportDefine'!C4:C5&'[LBA-LogiCal_CC_150603.xlsm]TransportDefine'!D4:D5&'[LBA-LogiCal_CC_150603.xlsm]TransportDefine'!E4:E5"`

SheetString 
`"WS_LOTR&'[LBA-LogiCal_CC_150603.xlsm]WS_LOTR'!X6&'[LBA-LogiCal_CC_150603.xlsm]WS_LOTR'!X5&'[LBA-LogiCal_CC_150603.xlsm]WS_LOTR'!X9"`

Comment: What are: the value of `j` in `TblRng.Cells(1,j)` and the addresses of `TblRng` and `TblTrspt`

Comment: After some further testing the Application.Evaluate was giving Error2015, the total length of the formula is over 300chars so I believe this is causing an error as application.match has a max 255 char limit.

When I paste the values of RangeString and SheetString into Match in a cell of the worksheet it works fine.

Comment: @EEM and Dan, can you edit the question with all of the stuff that is in these comments (and then delete the comments)?  This question is impossible for anyone else to follow and defeats the purpose of a community Q&A site.  It seems to be worth answering though.

Comment: Dan please let me know the value of J and the addresses of the ranges, so I can provide a full answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `WorkSite` is a `variable`, `TblRng` is a `Range` and `TblTrspt` is a `ListObject`; the following changes apply:

1. To set `SheetString`

> Currently I cannot get this code to compile as I get
>   "Application-defined object-defined error" on the line to set
>   SheetString.

Replaced `TblRng.Cells(1, j)` with `TblRng.Cells(1, j)` as `TblRng` is a `Range` not a `ListObject` as per:

> TblRng = Worksheets(WorkSite).Range("Tbl" & WorkSite)

```
With TblRng.Cells(1, j)
    SheetString = Worksheets(WorkSite).Range("E1").Address(External:=1)
    SheetString = SheetString & Chr(38) & .Offset(-5, 0).Address(External:=1)
    SheetString = SheetString & Chr(38) & .Offset(-6, 0).Address(External:=1)
    SheetString = SheetString & Chr(38) & .Offset(-2, 0).Address(External:=1)
End With
```

Replaced `.Address(False, False, , True)` with `.Address(External:=1)` as only external references are needed. Whether `references` are or not “*Absolute*” only matters if the formula is going to be written in the worksheet and copied further.

2. To set `RangeString`

`With TblTrspt
    RangeString = .ListColumns(1).Range.Address
    RangeString = RangeString & Chr(38) & .ListColumns(2).Range.Address
    RangeString = RangeString & Chr(38) & .ListColumns(3).Range.Address
    RangeString = RangeString & Chr(38) & .ListColumns(4).Range.Address
End With`

Replaced `.Address(False, False, , True)` with `.Address` in line with previous comment. Also in this case `External References` are not needed as the `Evaluate Method` is going to be applied to the `Worksheet` were the `ListObject` `TblTrspt` is located.

3. To Apply the `Evaluate Method` to the worksheet were `TblTrspt` is located.

   ```
   Eval = TblTrspt.Parent.Evaluate("MATCH(" & SheetString & "," & RangeString & ",0)")
   ```

Replaced `Application.Evaluate` with `TblTrspt.Parent.Evaluate`