# Excel VBA get row numbers in range matching multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get a match of the row number with a certain condition in my first sheet `Sheet1` and copy the format and paste it in the second sheet `Sheet2` where the lookup value matches.

I have data in Sheet1 like this:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | Title | condition |
| 1 | color1 | A |
| 2 | color2 | B |
| 3 | color4 | C |
| 4 | color2 | D |
| 5 | color1 | A |
| 6 | color2 | D |

And in Sheet2 like this:

like this:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Title | condition |  |
| 1 | color1 | A |  |
| 2 | color2 | D |  |
| 3 | color5 | C |  |
| 4 | color2 | B |  |

I came to the following code for accomplishing this for the first column matches (result in column C):

```
Sub colorcopy()

 

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, lookup1 As Range, lookup2 As Range, result As Range

Dim mtch As Variant

Dim i As Long, lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long

 

Set ws1 = Sheet1

Set ws2 = Sheet2

 

With ws1

    lr1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

End With

 

With ws2

    lr2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

End With

 

Set rng1 = ws1.Range("A1:A" & lr1)

Set rng2 = ws1.Range("B1:B" & lr1)

 

    For i = 1 To lr2

 

Set lookup1 = ws2.Range("A" & i)

Set lookup2 = ws2.Range("B" & i)

 

Set result = ws2.Range("C" & i)

   

    mtch = Application.Match(lookup1, rng1, 0)

   

    If Not IsError(mtch) Then

        ws1.Range("A" & mtch).Copy result

    End If

   

    Next i

 

End Sub
```

But then I wanted the code to work with multiple conditions (2).

I want to copy the cells of where there’s a match in data from both column A and column B from lookup values in Sheet1 to match in Sheet2.

In formula form this would be accomplished like `=MATCH(1,INDEX((Range1=Value1)*(Range2=Value2),),0)` for the first row. This seems not possible to be used in `Application.Match`, but I get stuck here.

Color of sheet1 is like this:

[image: pic1]

Result of current code is like this:

[image: pic2]
Wanted result is:

[image: pic3]

Comment: Good point. Edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27791053/9758194) is an older post on the matter, however (as I previously mentioned in a comment) it's rarely a good idea to concatenate values when you lookup/match any value. Rather use the following formula:

```
=MATCH(1,INDEX((Range1=Value1)*(Range2=Value2),),0)
```

In your current code, this would lead to a single change:

```
mtch = Application.Match(lookup1, rng1, 0)
```

Into;

```
mtch = ws1.Evaluate("MATCH(1,(A:A=""" & lookup1.Value & """)*(B:B=""" & lookup2.Value & """),0)")
```

**Note1:** Since this is an array-formula it may be process-heavy and computing time can become substantial

**Note2**: The worksheets-formula holds a nested `INDEX()` which is no longer needed since *Evalute()* will handle all formulae as though they were CSE-entered.

Comment: Sweet, it works. I noticed that if I code it as `.."MATCH(1,A1:A5 =..` it runs faster, but if I try `.."MATCH(1,A1:A """  & lr2= & """..` I get a run-time error 13 (type mismatch). Do you know a workaround?

Comment: I managed to get it by creating a string of the range I wanted to match against. `Dim a String` `a = "A1:A" & lr2` and refer to it as `..MATCH(1,(" & a & " = """ & lookup1.Value ..`